# postfix header_checks to rename email subject

Tags: postfix

We have a number of external systems reading from our emails, and some are tripping over others. Basically what I need to do is replace an email subject like:

```
[RT #179497] Internal: blah blah
```

with

```
[RT 179497] Internal: blah blah
```

So drop the hash. Does anyone know the regex to achieve this with postfix header_checks?

Comment: Sorry, we would also want the rewrite to only occur if it is destined for a particular address, so if it is addressed to example@whatever.com

Answer (score 4):

See [header_checks(5)](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) for examples and http://www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html#limitations for additional information.

Modifying the example in the mentioned man page is not that hard:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf:**

```
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre
```

**/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre:**

```
/^Subject: \[RT #(\d)\] Internal: (.+)$/    REPLACE Subject: [RT $1] Internal: $2
```

It could probably be done more elegant or shorter, but that's your job now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by @joschi (and I know this is late but someone else might find this information helpful): You indicated that you only want to rewrite headers on messages for certain e-mail addresses. This is a bit tricky:

You need to set up a separate transport so that you can specify different manipulation for messages using this transport:

default location: `/etc/postfix/transport`

```
example1@test.com   rewriter:
example2@test.com   rewriter:
.anotherdomain.com  rewriter:
```

This instructs postfix to process mails destined for these locations using the `rewriter` transport. Then, in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, you can add:

```
rewriter     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
  -o smtp_header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/rewrite_headers
```

And finally, you specify what sort of rewriting you want to actually do in the `/etc/postfix/rewrite_headers` file. It has the same syntax as the default `header_checks` file, it's just a custom version only valid for mails passing through the `rewriter` transport.

Note, this will probably not work if you have any sort of content filter active (for example Amavis), though in my case I was running a different manipulation.